# Data transformation to new min & max

Tags: data-transformation

I have a dataset and I was wondering if it is possible to transform the data to a new min, max range but while keeping the standard deviation of the dataset the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add or subtract a constant. That will increase or decrease the min and max by the same amount. What cannot be done is to multiple the min and max by a constant other than 1. If you multiply the data by some fraction, then the standard deviation will also be multiplied by that constant.

Let's suppose you have a min, max and standard deviation that you want to transform by something more complicated. For example, suppose that the distribution is normal squared. If you take the square root, the min and max and standard deviation would then be from a normal distribution, those measures are then what actually characterize the normal squared distribution, not the actual ones in the data. That is, when we transform data, the new parameters still reflect those of the original distribution, in a manner of speaking. So the answer is yes you can, but it doesn't mean anything.